# Windows GUI and native C++

Tags: c++, mfc, mixed-mode, ice

I'm making a student project called "C++ Game Development". It's a card game with client and server. Client application contains few windows which I've already made with Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2013. For client/server communication I decided to use [Internet Communications Engine (ICE)](http://www.zeroc.com). During Build in client's project I had errors in auto-generated code by ICE. I found that ICE doesn't support C++/CLI, only native C++ or C# (that I can't use).

So now I am at a crossroads, whether make the whole client application in native C++ (that means for ex. use MFC which I'm not familiar with) or use both native C++ and C++/CLI (put the work I've done with Windows Forms to CLR Class Library and link to it from native C++ project with entry point) which is also not trivial.

I'm trying to choose the less time-consuming option. I'm asking to help me estimate the complexity of these approaches. I like the second much more but I'm not sure it's the easiest.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`Qt` library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29)? This is a well-supported, very commonly used alternative to MFC.

Comment: No, it is actually my first Windows GUI application. Before that I've learned C++ in console apps.

Comment: You're easiest answer is probably to link your C++/CLI project against the C# ICE.  Easy peasy.  The C# interface is basically a C++/CLI interface anyway, the differences should be mostly syntactical.  https://www.zeroc.com/icedotnet.html says "In addition, the Ice run time can be used from other .NET languages, such as Visual Basic" (and C++/CLI is a .NET language)

Comment: Mooing Duck, I'm not sure I understood correct, but if you suggested to use C# layer in my client application, then I'm not allowed to use C# in my student project. I had this idea also. I checked ICE worked fine with C#. But professor said 'No'.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to use C++/CLI?

Comment: I'm allowed, but limited, mostly for GUI of client app. Besides my client app. does not contain any game logic, everything is implemented on the server and that is the largest part in native C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CLI can use native C++ code just fine.

Stick the generated code into a "static library project" that builds without `/clr`.  Then list that static library as a dependency of your C++/CLI DLL.

The linker will figure out the rest.  The result is called a "mixed-mode assembly".

Note that your comm library may not accept managed types.  That's ok, C++/CLI can perfectly well mix unmanaged data model and managed view (UI) classes.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried today few sample solutions in Visual Studio where I created native C++ static or dynamic libraries, put there ICE-generated code and referenced it from "CLR Console Application" project. It worked fine in both cases. It happened to be much easier than I thought. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) MSDN article helped me.
Is it critical to use exactly static library not dynamic for "mixed-mode assembly" or it doesn't matter?
Why then C++/CLI wrappers for native C++ classes are needed for? Initially I thought I needed that.

Comment: You can use a dynamic library, but then you'll have an extra DLL file which must be available at runtime.  With a static library, whatever code is actually used gets pulled into the main managed assembly (making it mixed-mode), so you only need the one file at runtime.  Also note that if you use a DLL for the native code, the native DLL-loading rules are followed, not the .NET assembly rules.  Different search paths, different errors when the file is not found.  Using the combined "mixed-mode" DLL is just easier.

Comment: C++/CLI wrappers are used as glue in between C# (or F# or VB.NET or any other .NET language) and native C++ code.  C++/CLI can use the native code directly (which is a very good thing, since that is what makes writing wrappers possible)  This C++ interop feature actually is officially called "It Just Works" :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends how much complexity is already in your GUI. If you have a hundred dialogs/controls then rewriting it in native C++ might be the wrong answer. In this case, making your GUI into a library makes more sense.

However, its probably a better option to keep your GUI as a process and build a proxy library in native C++ that passes the ICE calls onto your server. (so C++/CLI exe calls a function in a new C++ library that makes a ICE call to the server and vice-versa).

If your GUI is small, then rewriting it in a modern (and better supported that C++/CLI) system is the best thing. Qt is probably the ultimate in native GUIs nowadays (but there are alternatives such as MFC, or wxWidgets). Even in these cases, its still probably better to code your networking subsystem as a native library anyway. Then you can change your GUI and try out a load of the GUI stacks as you like, porting your game to Android or iOS with just 1 presentation layer change.

The third alternative is to choose a different comms system. Whilst RPC like ICE are nice, the 'where its at' today is web-based comms via REST services (try an embedded c++ webserver like Mongoose or NxWeb), if you need to push data back to the client, these support WebSockets, so will provide all the functionality you need. And then, you can rewrite your GUI to be HTML based!

So: put your comms in a native C++ library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer with different options to choose. My managed GUI isn't complex, so I'm looking forward to try remake to a native one with Qt. Besides Qt is compatible with ICE and has add-in for Visual Studio.

Comment: I also think that putting communications to a native C++ library is very reasonable. Really makes it easier porting the app. to other OS. Initially I was thinking about different, opposite architecture. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: There's nothing *native* in a Qt GUI. It's the last option to consider for a Windows only application. Everything else (even not using a library altogether) will result in a higher quality GUI than Qt will allow for.

Comment: @IInspectable that's like saying there's nothing native in a WPF GUI. Its native code which is what the OP was asking about, Qt is an excellent toolkit, and frankly Windows today is such a mess of GUI styles and technologies there is no native style to it anymore. The days of Windows Style Guidelines are long gone, alas.

Comment: When I said there's nothing native about Qt I was referring to the fact, that Qt has completely rewritten widgets from the ground up, without using any OS features (except for rendering). Most notably, Qt doesn't reuse control logic (as it did in Qt 3). Instead of reusing code that has been tried and tested, and is in active use by billions, Qt decided to roll its own, and gets it wrong more often than not. While you seem to be very visually focused, there's more to a quality GUI than visuals: A usable keyboard interface is equally important. Qt is atrociously inept in that department.

Comment: which one produce the smallest binary under windows release?